# Streaming live H.264 video via RTSP to iphone does work! w/example

Tags: iphone, streaming, ffmpeg, rtsp

Using FFMPEG, Live555, JSON

Not sure how it works but if you look at the source files at  http://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone  you can see that they are using a combination of open source projects like FFMPEG, Live555, JSON etc. Using Wireshark to sniff the packets sent from one of the public cameras that's available to view with the free  "Dropcam For Iphone App" at the App Store, I was able to confirm that the iphone was receiving H264 video via RTP/RTSP/RTCP and even RTMPT which looks like maybe some of the stream is tunneled?

Maybe someone could take a look at the open source files and explain how they got RTSP to work on the iphone.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the info TinC0ils. After digging a little deeper I'v read that they have modified the Axis camera with custom firmware to limit the streaming to just a single 320x240 H264 feed, to better provide a consistent quality video over different networks and, as you point out, be less of a draw on the phone's hardware etc. My interest was driven by a desire to use my iphone to view live video and audio from a couple of IP cameras that I own without the jerkiness of MJPEG or the inherent latency that is involved with "http live streaming". I think Dropcam have done an excellent job with their hardware/software combo, I just don't need any new hardware at the moment.

Oh yeah, I almost forgot the reason of this post  RTSP PROTOCOL DOES WORK ON THE IPHONE!

Answer (score 0):

They are using open source projects to receive the frames and decoding in software instead of using hardware decoders.  This will work, however, this runs counter to Apple's requirement that you use their HTTP Streaming.  It will also require greater CPU resources such that it doesn't decode video at the desired fps/resolution on older devices and/or decrease battery life compared to HTTP streaming.